# TypeError: can't dump MatchData

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activesupport

I've inherited an app from another developer and have added an error notification service, and have now received 1,408 occurrences of an error that I am having trouble getting to the bottom of...

The error is simply:

> TypeError: can't dump MatchData

with only non-project frames in the stack trace....

I can see where this error is ultimately occurring in the activesupport gem message_verifier.rb file, but I assume that there's an error in the application or configuration that is causing it originally, and am not sure the best approach how to trace this back to its point of origin on our end. Strikes me as the kind of thing that someone may look at and immediately see recognize it. And advice appreciated....

This is the stack trace:

```
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.2/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb" line 53 in dump
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.2/lib/active_support/message_verifier.rb" line 53 in generate
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.22.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb" line 300 in []=
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.22.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cookie_store.rb" line 64 in set_cookie
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb" line 335 in commit_session
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb" line 211 in context
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rack-1.4.7/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb" line 205 in call
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.22.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb" line 341 in call
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.22.2/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb" line 64 in call
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.22.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb" line 479 in call
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.22.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb" line 28 in block in call
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb" line 405 in _run__656928281__call__438689938__callbacks
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb" line 405 in __run_callback
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb" line 385 in _run_call_callbacks
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.22.2/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb" line 81 in run_callbacks
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.22.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb" line 27 in call
File "xxx/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.2.22.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb" line 31 in
```

Comment: With stuff like this I'd probably just try doing a global search for `=~` and `.match`, among others, to see where anything that returns `MatchData` is getting invoked

Comment: Are you able to reproduce the error or does it seem to happen at random?

Comment: @Jordan I haven't been able to reproduce – it's happening at various URLS none of which produce the error when I visit

Comment: @flanger001 I tried that too and didn't come to any conclusions, but the fact that I wasn't getting any application stack trace made me wonder if I was on the wrong track. Perhaps I will dig deeper on that.

Comment: It *seems* like the problem is that some code is trying to store a MatchData object (returned by various RegExp methods, e.g. `String#match`) in the session, which doesn't work because ActiveSupport doesn't know how to serialize a MatchData object (and why should it?). However, if you can't reproduce this it's going to be pretty hard to narrow down the cause. Since it apparently has to do with sessions, to reproduce it you may need to duplicate the problem session data in your own environment, which may require adding some additional logging and then waiting for the error to happen again.